# Is 甭 just the amalgamation of 不 and 用?

Tags: etymology

Can't think of any right now, but I have seen other characters which are really 2 characters combined.

Is 甭 just the amalgamation,phonetically and graphically, of 不 and 用, or some other provenance?

我的朋友们也说：“甭去了！

Comment: yes, the pronunciations are similar when you read them fast

Comment: Common in northern china, can be replaced with “别”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in phonetics, `甭` belongs to the Synaeresis word. What's more, it is also considered the Ideogrammic Character, since the meaning of `甭` is precisely the meaning of combining words `不(no)用(need)` .  There is a similar word, `嫑`, which in phonetics and the ideogrammic construction methods are also very much like `甭`. The meaning of `嫑` is `不(no)要(want)`. The opposite word of it is 嘦, means `只(only)要(want)`.

Besides this, there are also dozens of words that are Ideogrammic Characters,  such as

| Character | English Meaing | Separated Characters & Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `歪` | askew | `不(not)正 (upright)` |
| `孬` | weak | `不(not) 好 (good)` |

Comment: Excellent examples. They didn't pop up in my head.

Comment: 歪 does not quite belong here, though, does it. The character is certainly logographic, but the word itself doesn't seem to originate from the phonetic fusion of its components, unlike 甭 and the rest.

Comment: While 歪 is logographically but not phonetically akin to 甭, 别 and 酱 are examples of the opposite case: phonetically but not logographically akin to 甭. Like 甭, they are used to indicate a phonetic contraction of two characters, respectively 不要 and 这样; unlike 甭, they don't show this in their written form. (I'm less certain about 别, but arguably the fact that its real meaning is "depart/differ/other", which is not too far from 不要 semantically, may have helped it become standard.)

Comment: Synaeresis is new word for me!

Comment: @Sanchuan, Yes, you are right, the `甭` and `嫑` are both akin to the phonetic fusion of `不用` and `不要` in pronunciations and logographically to the stacking combination of `不用` and `不要`, whereas the `歪` and `孬` are only logographically similar to their counterparts in the combination words of `不正` and `不好`.

Comment: @Pedroski Don't worry, it's not too much, and won't be used in formal writing. In fact words like `甭` and `嫑` are more likely to be the dialect in the north of the country,  the example you mentioned `甭去了！` is the 100% north style dialect.

Answer (score 2):

甭 was initially known to exist in the speaking language of northern Chinese for "不(bù)用(yòng)" with the combined sound of "béng", and later become a single word (合成字) of itself.